# Which way is faster and more proper to get information from parent component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm developing an app with Next.js.

I want to get query information via useRouter in Child component.
Which way is faster and more proper to get query information?

1. Pass props to each ChildComponent from ParentComponent

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { query } = router

  return (
    <>
      <ChildComponent query={query} />
      <ChildComponent query={query} />
    </>
  )
}

const ChildComponent = ({ query }) => {
  console.log(query)

  return (
    <></>
  )
}
```

2. Get query in each ChildComponent

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ChildComponent />
      <ChildComponent />
    </>
  )
}

const ChildComponent = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { query } = router

  console.log(query)

  return (
    <></>
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked both? Generally the question to "is X faster than Y" is better answered by testing both operations in context of how they are applied (unless we are talking about things like complexity analysis). This is likely a case where it simply doesn't matter in practice. In terms of "what is proper", that is generally opinion, and can depend on many different factors in practice (such as how decoupled you want the parent or child to be from the overall application state and how you divvy up responsibility across components)

Comment: No, I didn't test which is faster. You're right. Thank you. I'm going to test it.

Comment: One of the nice parts of React Hooks is that they allow you to avoid passing props everywhere. I'd lean towards option 2.